# Как расставить здесь знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

`Мне в ВК (?) а (?) точнее не мне, а моему другу (?) написал мошенник.`

Как расставить знаки? Только без вставной конструкции, если можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне в ВК — а точнее, не мне, а моему другу — написал мошенник.

Мне в ВК (а точнее, не мне, а моему другу) написал мошенник.

Иначе никак, и другие Леопольдовы варианты отпадают.

Между **а** и **точнее** зап не нужна.

Comment: Нусне все, но согласен с вами.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты есть. Выбирайте в соответствии с тем, что вы хотите подчеркнуть-таки-с, сэр.

> Мне в ВК, а точнее не мне, а моему другу написал мошенник.

> Мне в ВК, а — точнее — не мне, а моему другу написал мошенник.

> Мне в ВК — а точнее не мне, а моему другу — написал мошенник.

> Мне в ВК (а точнее не мне, а моему другу) написал мошенник.

> Мне в ВК (а — точнее — не мне, а моему другу) написал мошенник.